# How to find last date with sales starting from yesterday with DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax, tabular

I have a calculated column "LastSaleDate" that finds the last date with sales with the following dax expression:
LastSaleDate=LASTDATE(filter(ALL(Dim_Time[Date]),[Sales Amount] >0))

What I want to achieve next is to create another calculated column "LastSaleDateStartingFromYesterday". So for example if the current date is Monday and there are no sales on Sunday or Saturday it should return Friday as the last date with sales (See example below). It is possible that Saturday and Sunday have Sales so I cannot exlude/filter them out.

How to write such a dax expression ?

[image]

All tips, solutions and help are highly appreciated

Best regards, Rubrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that your calculation for last sales date is not properly applying the filter for [Sales Amount] > 0. You can see this if you add an additional row for 2022-05-17 where [Sales Amount] = 0.

Here are the DAX formulas that worked for me:

```
LastSaleDate2 = CALCULATE(
MAX('Table'[Date]),
FILTER('Table','Table'[Sales Amount]>0)
)

LastSaleDateStartingFromYesterday2 = CALCULATE(
MAX('Table'[Date]),
FILTER('Table','Table'[Sales Amount]>0 && VALUE('Table'[Date]) < VALUE(TODAY()-1))
)
```

These can be converted to True/False by adding "= 'Table'[Date]" to the end of the formula.

[image: results]

Comment: Hey StrictlyFunk,
CALCULATE(
MAX(Dim_Time[Date]),FILTER(Fact_InternetSales,[Sales Amount]>0)
)
works fine but the second expression for PreviousSalesDate just gives me blank
CALCULATE(
MAX(Dim_Time[Date]),FILTER(InternetSales,[SalesAmount]>0 && value(Fact_SalesBudget[Sale date])  < VALUE(TODAY()-1))
)

Comment: My bad I had to FORMAT(TODAY(),"yyyyMMdd") then it worked

Answer (score 1):

You can add a calculated column:

```
PreviousSalesDate = 
var sDate = Sales[Date]
var lDate = CALCULATE(max(Sales[Date]), FILTER(Sales, sDate > Sales[Date] && Sales[Sales Amount] > 0))
return lDate
```

We work with variables in the code. sDate is teh current date of the row. Next we get the max of all rows where the date is smaller than the sDate (all rows before) and the sales is bigger than zero.

By the data you have given we only get the 13th of may.
[image]

Comment: Thank you Aldert, your solution worked aswell !